# WINDOWS to Linux character set issue

Tags: sql, linux, perl

I have different set of SQL files which has French/Spanish and other language characters. In windows, we are able to see the specific language characters and when it transfers to Linux and i see weird characters.

I understand windows uses different character set like WINDOWS-1252, WINDOWS-1258 and iso-8859-1.

How can we change the charset which is similar to Windows in Linux, So that we won't insert the weird characters in DB when triggering the queries from Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about what is on-topic here.  You may have better luck asking on the [DB Administrators'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: This is tagged Perl, so I'm guessing you're using DBI? Show your buggy code, cause it should be as simple as changing the encoding when you read the input file. Also, what database server are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlplus along with perl code not DBI module because it's not just insert, update and has procedures, triggers and views.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you have SQL scripts produced in a variety of windows encodings that include non-ASCII characters.  You want to execute these scripts on Linux.

I would think you'd want to lossless-ly convert the files to something that your linux SQL parser can handle, probably to unicode UTF-8.  This sort of conversion can be done with iconv (command-line utility, I believe there are libraries as well).

A challenge though is whether or not you know what each file's original encoding is, as this cannot necessarily be automatically detected...might be better if you can get the script files' authors to provide the scripts with a specified encoding.

Comment: I tried to use both iconv and recode commands in Linux but those two commands didn't solve my problem. Because I n Ed to determine the source encoding. BTW, I am trying to automate the DB deployment using perl, sqlplus.

Comment: As others mentioned, it's better to *know* the source encoding for certain because automatic detection is imperfect.  However there are utilities and libraries that attempt to to do this: try looking into "chardet", I believe there are various libraries and ports.

Answer (score 0):

> In windows, we are able to see the specific language characters

You can open it in notepad++ and see what encoding the file is using and you can also convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: No, you can see the encoding Notepad++ is guessing. To know which encoding the file is using, you have to ask to person who wrote it.

Comment: This is still useful advice, because Notepad++ can be used to change it. That should work most of the time, unless it guessed wrong. But it's better than guessing yourself.

Comment: I am trying to automate the FB deployment using perl, sqlplus. We don't want DB team to tell us what character set they are using. The workflow is WINDOWS->SCM->Linux->DB

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) or [utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) modules.
Normally for SQL or MySQL you will set the DB encoding to what you prefer to work with. These days most people set it to UTF-8 to support a large range of character sets.

But in this case you can play around with the encoding to match the right one needed, This could work.

```
use Encode qw(decode encode); 
$data = encode("utf8", decode("iso-8859-1", $data));
```